# How to add event at mapbox popup

Tags: angular, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, mapbox-marker

I need to know how to use events like `mouseover`, `click` for the popup, when the popup is opened. I can't find anything about this functionality for **Angular**.

When the popup is opened I need to handle `mouseover` event for this popup! Thanks!

```
   const popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({
        offset: 25,
        anchor: 'left',
        className: 'popup',
    });
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
    popup.setDOMContent(this.toolTip.nativeElement);
    let coords = this.reverseCoords(
        this.segmentsArray[index]?.segmentLocation.coordinates as any
    );
    const marker = new mapboxgl.Marker()
        .setLngLat(coords)
        .setPopup(popup)
        .addTo(this.map);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the event at DOM and it will work.
( i had a mistake at my HTML and it didn't worked)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).